# Remove gap between HTML body elements

Tags: html, css

Inside of the body element, I'm finding an immutable margin between its child elements. I made a codepen example to help explain my problem, http://codepen.io/Krail/pen/gbGWad.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Case 1 -->
<header><p>HeaderParagraph1</p></header>
<main><p>MainParagraph1</p></main>
<footer><p>FooterParagraph1</p></footer>

<!-- Case 2 -->
<p id="head">HeaderParagraph2</p>
<p id="main">MainParagraph2</p>
<p id="foot">FooterParagraph2</p>
```

**CSS**

```
body {background-color: grey; border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0}

/* Case 1 */
header {background-color: yellow; border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0}
main {background-color: orange; border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0}
footer {background-color: pink; border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0}

/* Case 2 */
p#head {background-color: yellow; border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0}
p#main {background-color: orange; border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0}
p#foot {background-color: pink; border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0}
```

Case 1 is an example of my problem. Case 2 is my desired effect.

Any insight into the html principle at play here would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `<p>` has a standard margin in browsers. You can set them to `margin:0;`

Answer (score 1):

Other than just `header { ... }` do `header p { ... }`, and so on for each one:

```
header p {background-color: yellow; border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0}
main p {background-color: orange; border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0}
footer p {background-color: pink; border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0}
```

Here is an example [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYMbBG).

Comment: This example was meant to be as simple as possible. In real practice, I wouldn't of used a `<p>` element (but rather an `<h1>` element) and I also would've done `header > h1 { . . . }` to be painfully precise since it directly follows the `<header>`. element

Thanks for the reply though.